# giving embedded links to images in iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, uikit, uibutton, twitter

I am creating an application using the Twitter API. I have retrieved the profile image and it is shown fine in my application.

Now I need to add an embedded link to the profile image so that clicking on that image will navigate to the users profile page on twitter. How would this be done?

Comment: What are you doing? Native app or web based? What do you mean "embedded link"? you want to push an other view on stack? you want to load an request on an web view? or you want to open an url scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a custom UIButton on the top of the UIImageView with the profile image and assign a Touch Up Inside action with sth like that:

```
-(IBAction)goToTwitter {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"address you wanna go to"]]; 
}
```

This will launch Safari with the address given.

You can also use a sole UIButton (without UIImageView) - in that case just assign a user profile image to the image property of the button.